# Concatenating images in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I wish to concatenate parts of an image to make another image. The initial image is to be divided into 25 parts and concatenated in another 4D matrix to get the reconstructed image. However the reconstructed image is always a completely white image.

Here is the code.

```
im = zeros(600,482,3,25); %4D matrix initilization 
k = 1;

            for i = 0:4

                for j = 0:4

                    im(:,:,:,k) = image(i*600+1:(i+1)*600, j*482+1:(j+1)*482,:); %assigning image parts to the larger image 
                    img_here = image(i*600+1:(i+1)*600, j*482+1:(j+1)*482,:); % to check if the copied portion is correct
                    imshow(img_here); % displays correct image portion 
                    imshow(im(:,:,:,k)); %always displays a completely white portion 
                    k = k+1; % position conter increment. 

                end

            end
```

Comment: Try using `imshow(...,[])` for an automatic scaling.

Comment: Also I think your code get's more readable if you use `i*600 + (1:600)` instead of `i*600+1:(i+1)*600`

Comment: Also why do you doubt that `img(:,:,:,k)` is in any way different from `img_here`?

Comment: I don't doubt it. Since i wasn't getting the correct answer. I used it as a sanity check and it failed. Both imshow's yield different results. Which is the most strange thing.

Comment: Did you check what types you get in `img_here` and in `im`? `imshow` does different things for different types.

Comment: I just did. That was the problem. Thanks a lot.